# Trouble with GPU in VS Code after connecting to a remote server

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, gpu, tensorflow2.0

I have configured TensorFlow with an NVIDIA GPU on my local machine, and initially, I was able to utilize my local GPU within VS Code. However, after connecting to a remote server and opening a new window, my local VS Code can no longer access my GPU (although the remote server's GPU is accessible). Interestingly, PyCharm can detect my GPU.

Here's the code I'm running:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.constant(1.)
b = tf.constant(2.)
print(a + b)
print(tf.__version__)
print(tf.test.gpu_device_name())
print('GPU:', tf.config.list_physical_devices(device_type='GPU'))
print('CPU:', tf.config.list_physical_devices(device_type='CPU'))
print(tf.test.is_gpu_available())
```

In PyCharm, the output is as follows:

```
tf.Tensor(3.0, shape=(), dtype=float32)
2.9.0
/device:GPU:0
GPU: [PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
CPU: [PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:CPU:0', device_type='CPU')]
True
```

However, in VS Code, I get the following error:

```
Could not load dynamic library 'cusolver64_11.dll'; dlerror: cusolver64_11.dll not found
2023-11-01 23:38:43.654110: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1850] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use the GPU. Follow the guide at [TensorFlow GPU Installation Guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu) for how to download and set up the required libraries for your platform.
```

However, 'cusolver64_11.dll' does exist on my computer.
Can someone help me resolve this issue? Any insights would be greatly appreciated.